# Samsung C460W network printer drops out of network after some time

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, network-printer

I have a Samsung C460W Wi-Fi network printer. Once set up, the printer works perfectly, or at least satisfying for me. Connected to the Wi-Fi network using the WPS button on the printer, the printer (in theory) easily connects to the network. For some time, the printer works as expected.

But after some time the printer loses connection to the network. When I use my app it says "device not found". It then takes to much unnecessary time to get the printer connected to the network again. This happens every time and somehow can only be fixed by resetting the network settings in the printer and connecting it again to the network using the wps button.

I cannot find whether this is caused by a change in the router/network or that the printer has it's own 'bug' making the printer lose the connection to the network.

I would like to solve this but I don't know how I can. What might be the cause of this problem?

[image]

The wireless indicator should be blue.